# problems installing cisco vpn client on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cisco-vpn-client

I am trying to install cisco vpn client on my ubuntu box but getting errors that I dont know how to resolve.

I am trying the following client: http://projects.tuxx-home.at/?id=cisco_vpn_client

I downloaded 4.8.01 and my ubuntu version is jaunty (9.04).  Below are the errors that I get while trying to install

```
Making module
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.28-14-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/bhaarat/Downloads/vpnclient modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-14-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/bhaarat/Downloads/vpnclient/linuxcniapi.o
In file included from /home/bhaarat/Downloads/vpnclient/Cniapi.h:15,
                 from /home/bhaarat/Downloads/vpnclient/linuxcniapi.c:31:
/home/bhaarat/Downloads/vpnclient/GenDefs.h:113: error: conflicting types for ‘uintptr_t’
include/linux/types.h:40: error: previous declaration of ‘uintptr_t’ was here
make[2]: *** [/home/bhaarat/Downloads/vpnclient/linuxcniapi.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/bhaarat/Downloads/vpnclient] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-14-generic'
make: *** [default] Error 2
Failed to make module "cisco_ipsec.ko".
```

Can someone tell me how to resolve this or suggest some other cisco vpn for ubuntu that you know works?

Furthermore, after i get the vpn and am able to connect ...will I be able to RDP into a window machine from ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a way of connecting to my office VPN on Jaunty, and I used vpnc, with [this article](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-connect-to-a-cisco-vpn-using-vpnc) as a reference successfully.